# prevent null pointer in map() reduce() of java 8 for BigDecimal additions

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to add all the prices of given products as:

```
 BigDecimal getTotalPrice(List<Product> products) {
        return products.stream()
                .map(Product::getPrice)
                .peek(bigDecimal -> System.out.println(bigDecimal))
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    }
```

I tried printing all the values of `bigDecimal`, whenever we get value as `null` we are getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`, is there any better way to addition in the `java 8` by preventing any kind of Exceptions?

Comment: If you want to filter them out add `.filter(bigDecimal  -> bigDecimal != null)` or `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` before `reduce`

Comment: you can use filter operator before map, you can filter

 products.stream()
                .filter(x->x!=null)
                .map(Product::getPrice)
                .peek(bigDecimal -> System.out.println(bigDecimal))
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);


ore you can use Optional wrapper


 .map(x-> Optionale.ofNullable(x.getPrice).orElse(0))

Comment: Note also that you can say `peek(System.out::println)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest adding intermediate filter steps:

```
return products.stream()
               .filter(Objects::nonNull) // If products can contain null values
               .map(Product::getPrice)
               .filter(Objects::nonNull) // If price can be null
               .peek(bigDecimal -> System.out.println(bigDecimal))
               .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```